# add html in the 'help' parameter of the formbuilder

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I use the `formbuilder` in a Symfony project.

I'd like to use as much as I can the `{{ form_row(form) }}` in my twig template to avoid writing `errors`, `label`, `help` and `widget` myself.

In this particular case, I'd like to add a link in the `form_help`. Is it possible to do it from the form builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it's possible to use HTML directly in the `'help'` option of the `formBuilder` like this:

```php
class TotoType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'help' => 'go tho the <a href="prenom.com">list</a> name'
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```